# Create Windows 10 AMI for EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-10, amazon-s3, amazon-ami

I have case to create AMI based on windows 10 OS, the AMI file will be used on AWS ec2 to run some our 3rd party programs for client. I have tried to follow several tutorial and guidelines from google and youtube. But the problem still persists when I finish upload to S3 and tried to convert file from ova or vhd to AMI with output status message as follows:

[status message output after convert vhd to ami](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW9V5.png)

Can anyone help us with this case?

Comment: This would be difficult to do. You'd be better off using an AWS Windows AMI, or AWS Workspaces with the Windows 10 experience.

Comment: we already try those options but unfortunately, we have to deploy desktop windows 10 on ec2 in order to fully utilize ec2 features on aws

Comment: I'm not sure AWS is the best fit for this. I hope you get it going or someone can help, if you do I'll read the answer with interest. You should also look at licensing, even if you get it going it might not be a good idea.